# Issue with setting value in localstorage in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm trying to save values in local storage. It's saves an empty array on local storage for first time when i clicked on Set Item. After that this code works normally. I'm beginner in react & ts. Here's the code below.

**hooks/useLocalStorage.ts**

```js
function useLocalStorage(key: string) {
  /* Set Item to Localstorage */
  const set = (value: unknown) => {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log((error as Error)?.message);
    }
  };

  /* Get Item from Localstorage */
  const get = () => {
    try {
      return localStorage.getItem(key);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  /* Remove Item */
  const clean = () => {
    try {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log((error as Error)?.message);
    }
  };

  return { set, get, clean };
}

export { useLocalStorage };
```

**App.tsx**

```js
import { Button, ButtonGroup, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useLocalStorage } from "./hooks/useLocalStorage";

function App() {
  type TProp = {
    title: string;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const { set, get, clean } = useLocalStorage("todos");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<TProp[]>([]);

  /* Set Item */
  const setItem = () => {
    setTodos([...todos, { title: value }]);
    set(todos);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="Enter Text"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        margin="normal"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ButtonGroup variant="contained" fullWidth>
        <Button onClick={setItem}>Set Item</Button>
        <Button color="success" onClick={() => console.log(get())}>
          Get Item
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="error"
        fullWidth
        sx={{ mt: 2 }}
        onClick={clean}
      >
        Remove Item
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**main.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I tried to log values from useLocalStorage and App.tsx.

Used **useEffect** hook to create an empty array with same name but didn't wprked.

**App.tsx**

```js
/** ... **/

useEffect(() => {
  if(get()?.length === 0) {
    /* todos is empty at this moment */
    set(todos)
  }
},[])

/** ... **/
```

Upper code works perfectly and as expected it creates an empty Array named **todos** in localstorage, but still if I add some value on Input and click on **Set** for the first time it didn't work.

Comment: When you need to add your todo data in localstorage?

Comment: Seems like a misleading API. Unless you're going to abstract and mangle the key, anyone using two of your components will end up with a collision. Also, you're not deserializing which is definitely a bug and your catch blocks are meaningless because the local storage API won't throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [**react `setState` is asynchronous,**<sup>[github]</sup>](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710) and `setItem` creates a closure over `const todos`, you will not immediately get an updated `todos` right after `setTodos([...todos, { title: value }])` so do not rely on `todos` being up to date when `set(todos)` fires.

I would suggest creating a temporary source of truth from which both `setTodos` and `set` will obtain their arguments.

Hence:

```
const setItem = () => {
  let __temp = [...todos, { title: value }]; 
  setTodos(__temp);
  set(__temp); /* <—- I no longer depend on setTodos updating todos because I now have my own source of truth. */
};
```